# Streaming Video from Linux to Windows

Tags: linux, windows, streaming, video, red5

I have been searching on the Internet but find no straight answer on what to use in this case. Basically, I have a client that has an Icecast radio streaming server running on Linux. People are able to listen to his radio by connecting on his website. This specific client would like to have a video streaming service where he can stream either a webcam stream or a straight video file to his linux server. People would then connect to a specific webpage to see the live video stream.

First, I would like to know if it is possible to stream video from VLC to Icecast and then connect to the Icecast mountpoint on the web in order to see the video.

Second, I would like to know if Red5 would be a good server software in case Icecast is not a good one.

Also with all those questions, what would be the protocol used and what would be the file format for the video files that he would like to stream.

Regards and thank you for the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

This question is borderline off-topic as you are essentially asking for a full solution.

Regardless, Icecast does provide both audio and video streaming and would work for a small number of clients.  Video streaming requires a LOT of bandwidth however and overall my recommendation would be to utilize a web host that specializes in video streaming to provide the client end-points.